# Linux Ubuntu 22.04 problem when hit command sudo apt update

Tags: 22.04

W: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy_InRelease' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

Comment: Did you edit your sources.list?

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi : Yes